# PHP | Pie chart from SQL database

Tags: php

I've been trying so far to create pie chart showing count of specific values.
My table has products rows, for each product it has service contract date.
What I need is the count of the **year** displaying in the contract_date column.

For example this table:

```
Product A   11-Nov-2019
Product B   21-Sep-2019
Product C   18-Oct-2020
Product D   23-Oct-2019
Product E   12-Jul-2019
Product F   10-Jun-2021
Product G   15-Jan-2020
Product H   24-Jan-2021
Product I   23-Oct-2019
Product J   21-Sep-2019
```

So the pie chart should show:

[image]

I wrote this code but I'm not able to do the count function correctly

```
<?php
//include the library
include "libchart/libchart/classes/libchart.php";

//new pie chart instance
$chart = new PieChart( 500, 300 );

//data set instance
$dataSet = new XYDataSet();

//actual data
//get data from the database

//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

//query all records from the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_database";

//execute the query
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

//get number of rows returned
$num_results = $result->num_rows;

if( $num_results > 0){

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
        extract($row);
        $Year = explode('-', $Service_contract);
        $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("{$Year[0]}", $Year[0]));
    }

    //finalize dataset
    $chart->setDataSet($dataSet);

    //set chart title
    $chart->setTitle("Expiry contracts year 2019-2023");
    
    //render as an image and store under "generated" folder
    $chart->render("libchart/demo/generated/1.png");

    //pull the generated chart where it was stored
    echo "<img alt='Pie chart'  src='/myfolder/libchart/demo/generated/1.png' style='border: 1px solid gray;'/>";

}else{
    echo "No programming languages found in the database.";
}
?>
```

The result of this code showing like this:

[image]

What should do to fix the problem? how can I count the values instead of showing it repeatedly ? how should I use the count function ?

Please advise

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the libchart documentation

Comment: Wouldn't you want a query like `SELECT YEAR(contract_date), COUNT(*) FROM my_database GROUP BY YEAR(contract_date)`?  (this of course assumes that `contract_date` is a DATE column)

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks man !! your comment just gave me a clue how to solve the problem , I'll post the answer .

Comment: @ac89live  Glad to help, but do see the comment under your answer.  You should be able to loop through a single result-set to the get same output.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I solved it this way ( **Thanks** to @PatrickQ )

```
<?php
.....
....
if( $num_results > 0){

$result0 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT count(*) as count0 FROM my_database where YEAR(Service_contract) = '2019'");
$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT count(*) as count1 FROM my_database where YEAR(Service_contract) = '2020'");
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT count(*) as count2 FROM my_database where YEAR(Service_contract) = '2021'");
$result3 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT count(*) as count3 FROM my_database where YEAR(Service_contract) = '2022'");
$result4 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT count(*) as count4 FROM my_database where YEAR(Service_contract) = '2023'");
$result0 = $result0->fetch_object();
$result1 = $result1->fetch_object();
$result2 = $result2->fetch_object();
$result3 = $result3->fetch_object();
$result4 = $result4->fetch_object();
$dataSet = new XYDataSet();
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("2019", $result0->count0));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("2020", $result1->count1));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("2021", $result2->count2));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("2022", $result3->count3));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("2023", $result4->count4));

    //finalize dataset
    $chart->setDataSet($dataSet);

    //set chart title
    $chart->setTitle("Expiry contracts year 2019-2023");

    //render as an image and store under "generated" folder
    $chart->render("libchart/demo/generated/1.png");

    //pull the generated chart where it was stored
    echo "<img alt='Pie chart'  src='/myfolder/libchart/demo/generated/1.png' style='border: 1px solid gray;'/>";

}else{
    echo "No programming languages found in the database.";
}
?>
```

And this is the result I was expecting:

[image]

I know this code is not dynamic and need to edit it from time to time, but for now this is answering my need.

Thanks :)

Comment: Check the comment again; if you correctly use `GROUP BY()` in conjunction with `SELECT(YEAR(), COUNT())` then you don't need to execute N queries for each year. This "works", but can be improved. I'd try now to figure that out; save you the time later :)